# Connection refused in wso2 playground2 sample

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am doing playground2 sample of wso2 from this [post](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/OpenID+Connect+with+the+WSO2+Identity+Server+and+WSO2+OAuth2+Playground). It is generating access token but having problem when I am accessing UserInfo.
It's saying **connection refused**. I am using wso2is-5.0.0

thank you

Comment: Can you share screenshots of what you have done? Then we will be able to identity the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below curl command for call userinfo endpoint and if you need more details you can use this [URL](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/03/09/openid-connect-support-with-resource-owner-password-grant-type/).

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer <paste_access_token>"   https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid
```

Plus you need to adding claims in OAuth service provider side and get more details in this offcial [WSO2 document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider).